# ¿Por qué aparecen archivos distintos a los que manipule en mi proyecto para hacer commit?

Tags: git

pongo una captura de los archivos que aparecen modificados, sin embargo yo no toque ni uno de estos, como hago para que dejen de aparecer, ya que, cada que termino de hacer un commit, por cualquier cosa que mueva o haga, nuevamente se generan estos.
agradezco la ayuda.
[image: archivos que se aparecen modificados]

psdta: realice limpiado de cache de git, porsiaca, nose si estuvo bien hacer eso.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer son archivos producidos por una compilación y con cada cambio se producirían archivos nuevos, para que éstos no se suben al repositorio, deberas agregar la carpeta al archivo .gitignore

```
folioreader/build
```

Comment: Gracias Jonathan, efectivamente, agregue los directorios que me sugieres al .ignore, y ya no se me cargan esos molestos archivos por cada cambio que hacia.

Comment: @Jhn si esto responde tu pregunta, márcala como aceptada. Puedes leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para guiarte